# We can able to call an ActionMethod without ActionVerb, Then why ActionVerb is provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When we can call an ActionMethod without Action Verb, why we need it

What is the real use of ActionVerb

Answer (score 0):

`ActionVerbs` is used when you want to control the selection of an action method based on a `Http` request method.

`ActionVerbs`, such as `HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpOptions & HttpPatch`. You can apply these attributes to action method to indicate the kind of `Http` request the action method supports. If you do not apply any attribute then it considers it a GET request by default.

For further Information. please read this article. [Action Verbs](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/actionverbs-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a little, if I said these two calls do different things, without knowing the verb, what would these URL's tell you?

mysite/api/mycontroller/1

versus

mysite/api/mycontroller/1

Trick question.  The first is a GET looking for a specific record.  The second is a PUT updating the record with the id of 1 (data is in body).  The REST spec requires/suggests the use of verbs and http status codes for clarity of communication.  Look up the different levels of REST compliance sometime.